# Get selected value from dynamic selection list

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I am working on a jsp project where I have a dynamic selection list. The values in this list change according to the value selected in the 1st selection list.
Here's the code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function optionsChange(){   
    var service = document.getElementById("service").value;
    if(service == 'GSM'){   
        document.getElementById("cdmaService").value= '';
        document.getElementById("cdmaService").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("gsmService").style.display = 'block';
        $('gsmService').attr('name', 'services');
    }else if(service == 'CDMA'){
        document.getElementById("gsmService").value= '';
        document.getElementById("gsmService").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("cdmaService").style.display = 'block';
        $('cdmaService').attr('name', 'services');
    }
  }
</script>

<select id="service" onChange="javascript:optionsChange();">
            <option value="GSM">GSM</option>
            <option value="CDMA">CDMA</option>
</select>

<td id="gsmService" ><select name="services" > 

            <option value="COMBO OFFER">COMBO OFFER</option>  
            <option value="CRICKET">CRICKET</option>
            <option value="ASTRO">ASTRO</option>
</select>   
</td>

<td id="cdmaService" style="display:none"><select name="services" >
            <option value="COMBO OFFER CDMA">COMBO OFFER CDMA</option>
             <option value="WIN THE DREAM">WIN THE DREAM</option>
            <option value="VOICE CHAT">VOICE CHAT</option>          
        </select>
 </td>
```

now when the user selects a service, lets say "GSM", and then selects a service from the second list, lets say "ASTRO". He clicks on a button which redirects him to the next page where he sees "ASTRO" printed. This works fine. 
But if the user selects "CDMA" from the 1st list and then selects, let's say "VOICE CHAT" from the second list. It still prints "ASTRO" on the next page. IT should print "VOICE CHAT".

this is the method to submit form:

```
<script language=javascript>

function submitForm(actionStr)
{
    if(actionStr=="User Details")
    {
        document.login.action="showUsrDetail.jsp";
        document.login.submit();
    } 
}
```

this is the code for the button:

```
<input type="button" value="User Details" onclick="submitForm(this.value);"/>
```

then it redirects to the page ""showUsrDetail.jsp". And when it does the name of the service is printed on the console. For which the code is:

```
<% 
    String service = request.getParameter("services");
    System.out.println("Value Added Service selected is ="+service);
%>
```

if i change the first selection to CDMA and then select any service from the second selection list, it still prints the Service which is under GSM.

Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: write a javascript function to get the value of the combobox instead of getting the same from servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a javascript function to get the selected value instead of getting the same from servlet. Put the Javascript function in script tab with language as JavaScript.

```
function JSGetSelectedItem() {
   var dropdownIndex = document.getElementById('service').selectedIndex;
   var dropdownValue = document.getElementById('service')[dropdownIndex].text;
} 

<select id="service" onChange="JSGetSelectedItem()">
            <option value="GSM">GSM</option>
            <option value="CDMA">CDMA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i wrote a function to get the selected values from both the lists.. ti worked..!! thank you :)